# How to scrape website contents using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using python how to scrape the contents from a website?

```
import re    
import time    
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import pandas as pd

def main():

    html = requests.get("https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/marketstats/pageno-1,pid-58,sortby-CurrentYearRank,sortorder-asc,year-2017.cms")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    jstr = {}
    lis = []
    code = ''
    comp = ''
    for link in soup.find_all(class_='w170 alignL'):

        print(link.get('href'))
        Name1 = link
        Name11 = str(Name1)
        Name2 = Name11.lstrip('</b>')
        Name = Name2.rstrip('</b>')
        print(Name)
        input()

        try:
            data = {'Name': Name}
            print('\n \n')
            lis.append(data)
            li = []
            p = re.compile('\w+')
            processed_texts = []
            processed_texts = p.findall(str(data))
            print("processed_texts",processed_texts)

        except:
            pass    

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main()
```

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Didnt get your question. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan: 
I mentioned one url in my code, from that url, I want to scrape the contents inside the class_='w170 alignL'

Comment: and what is the issue you are facing currently?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan:  I scrapped contents from other websites using the same code. but it is not working with this url

Comment: Please specify exactly what's not working. And what is `class_='w170 alignL'`? Which part of the page? Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @KeyurPotdar: go through this url : https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/marketstats/pageno-1,pid-58,sortby-CurrentYearRank,sortorder-asc,year-2017.cms

Comment: @KeyurPotdar: I just want to scrape the contents inside the  class_='w170 alignL'

Comment: Do you want links or names of the companies, or both?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar: I want  the contents inside href, for example :  href="/indian-oil-corporation-ltd/stocks/companyid-11924.cms"

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Thank you....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect the table, you can see that it is located inside this `<div data-curpg="1" class="dataContainer"> ... </div>` tag. But, if you view the page source, you'll this code: `<div data-curpg="1" class="dataContainer"><data_table></data_table></div>`.

The `<data_table>` content is dynamically generated with JS. You can't directly execute JS with `requests` module. You'll have to use Selenium for this purpose. For installation and demo, [check this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

You can use Selenium in this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

URL = 'https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/marketstats/pageno-1,pid-58,sortby-CurrentYearRank,sortorder-asc,year-2017.cms'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for li in soup.find_all('li', class_='w170 alignL'):
    a = li.find('a')
    company_name = a.text
    company_url = a['href']  # This is the link that you were looking for.
    # You can save or print these values however you want.
    print(company_name, company_url)
```

Output:

```
Indian Oil Corporation Ltd. /indian-oil-corporation-ltd/stocks/companyid-11924.cms
Reliance Industries Ltd. /reliance-industries-ltd/stocks/companyid-13215.cms
State Bank of India /state-bank-of-india/stocks/companyid-11984.cms
Tata Motors Ltd. /tata-motors-ltd/stocks/companyid-12934.cms
Rajesh Exports Ltd. /rajesh-exports-ltd/stocks/companyid-6650.cms
Bharat Petroleum Corporation Ltd. /bharat-petroleum-corporation-ltd/stocks/companyid-11941.cms
Hindustan Petroleum Corporation Ltd. /hindustan-petroleum-corporation-ltd/stocks/companyid-12078.cms
Oil And Natural Gas Corporation Ltd. /oil-and-natural-gas-corporation-ltd/stocks/companyid-11599.cms
Coal India Ltd. /coal-india-ltd/stocks/companyid-11822.cms
Tata Consultancy Services Ltd. /tata-consultancy-services-ltd/stocks/companyid-8345.cms
ICICI Bank Ltd. /icici-bank-ltd/stocks/companyid-9194.cms
Tata Steel Ltd. /tata-steel-ltd/stocks/companyid-12902.cms
Larsen & Toubro Ltd. /larsen-&-toubro-ltd/stocks/companyid-13447.cms
Hindalco Industries Ltd. /hindalco-industries-ltd/stocks/companyid-13637.cms
Bharti Airtel Ltd. /bharti-airtel-ltd/stocks/companyid-2718.cms
HDFC Bank Ltd. /hdfc-bank-ltd/stocks/companyid-9195.cms
Mahindra & Mahindra Ltd. /mahindra-&-mahindra-ltd/stocks/companyid-11898.cms
NTPC Ltd. /ntpc-ltd/stocks/companyid-12316.cms
Vedanta Ltd. /vedanta-ltd/stocks/companyid-13111.cms
Infosys Ltd. /infosys-ltd/stocks/companyid-10960.cms
Maruti Suzuki India Ltd. /maruti-suzuki-india-ltd/stocks/companyid-11890.cms
Housing Development Finance Corporation Ltd. /housing-development-finance-corporation-ltd/stocks/companyid-13640.cms
Wipro Ltd. /wipro-ltd/stocks/companyid-12799.cms
Axis Bank Ltd. /axis-bank-ltd/stocks/companyid-9175.cms
Punjab National Bank /punjab-national-bank/stocks/companyid-11585.cms
```